# Confirming the formula for the Spectral Density of a Matern Covariance Function

Tags: gaussian-process, covariance-function

The Matérn Class of functions is given by $$k_M(r)=\frac{2^{1-\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)}\left(\frac{r\sqrt{2\nu}}{l}\right)^{\nu} K_{\nu}\left(\frac{r\sqrt{2\nu}}{l}\right)$$ where $r=\Vert x-x'\Vert$. The function $K_\nu$ is the Modified Bessel of the 2nd kind. And its spectral density is given by:
$$S(x):=\frac{2^D\pi^{\frac{D}{2}}\Gamma(\nu+D/2)(2\nu)^{\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu)l^{2\nu}}\left(\frac{2\nu}{l^2}+4\pi^2 x^2\right)^{-(\nu+D/2)}$$, where $D$ is the dimension of $x$.

P.S.: For the definition of Matérn Covariance function and its spectral density, see [William and Rasmussen's book on GP(Chapter 4)](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf)

However, [in this R package](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/spectralGP/versions/1.3.3/topics/matern.specdens), we have [image]
 and they seem contradictory.

Which one is correct, and is there some bibliography for this? I've searched, but I couldn't find a link which I thought would  trustworthy.

Comment: They use slightly different notation and otherwise look algebraically identical: try $2x=\omega.$

Comment: @whuber thanks for the comment ;)